# PyTorch BatchNorm1D, 2D, 3D and TensorFlow/Keras BatchNormalization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I want to use `BatchNorm1D` like in PyTorch in TensorFlow. I notice that `BatchNormalization()` in TF has `axis=-1` as default. Which axis is the correct one for `BatchNorm1D, BatchNorm2D, BatchNorm3D` as in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ordering of dimensions.

Pytorch does its batchnorms over axis=1.
But it also has tensors with axis=1 as channels for convolutions.

Tensorflow has has channels in the last axis in convolution. So its batchnorm puts them in axis=-1.

In most cases you should be safe with the default setting.